# WordPress plugin admin html being shown in Customizer iframe

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-customizer, iframe

I have a WordPress plugin that is focused soley on the admin side of things.

I have a piece of HTML that is shown on all admin pages using the `all_admin_notices` hook. This worked very well, but I wanted to show it on the customizer page too. So I am also using this hook: `customize_register`.

```
function swatch()
{
 echo "hello";
}
add_action( 'all_admin_notices', 'swatch' );
add_action( 'customize_register', 'swatch' );
```

The issue I am facing is that on the customizer page it shows where it is meant to be. However my html is also being put within the iframe. So I see my html twice. Except in the iframe it is unstyled because the styles are not loaded within the iframe.

The plugin does not show anything on the front end of the website and I can confirm this by not seeing anything or in the source code when visiting the website.

I didn't think that using the customize_register hook would display this within the preview iframe? Is there a method to prevent this? Alternatively if I cannot prevent this can I load styles too? At least then I can display none or 1 of the blocks of html being displayed.